# TB_inline? onclick remove thickbox then show thickbox and div id from option value

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming, wordpress, thickbox

So I am working on some shortcodes when I click the shortcode button I am showing a thickbox window with a select box with the available shortcodes. When I click on a shortcode from the drop down I am showing that shortcodes options. The problem is when I choose a different shortcode from the select it shows the new shortcode options and the previous shortcode options. I want to remove the thickbox and then show the thickbox with the new selected div.

```
<script>
  function inlineId() {
    tb_remove();
    var optionValue = jQuery('select[name=shortcodeOptions]').val()
    tb_show("Choose a Shortcode", "#TB_inline?height=300&amp;width=400&amp;inlineId=" + optionValue + "");
    } 
</script>

<div id="shortcode_list" style="display:none">
    <label for="select">
        <span>Choose a shortcode</span>
    </label>
    <select name="shortcodeOptions">
        <option>Select a shortcode</option>
        <option onclick="inlineId()" value="alert_div">Alert</option>
        <option onclick="inlineId()" value="button_div">Button</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

With this code, when I select a new option, I can see the thickbox closing while changing the selected option at the same time but it doesn't display the thickbox after it closes.

Answer (score 1):

I went about it a different way. Not sure if this is the best solution but its working.

```
<script>
function showOptions() {
    var optionValue = jQuery('select[name=shortcodeOptions]').val()     
    jQuery('.sc_options').css('display','none');
    jQuery('.'+optionValue+'').css('display','block');
    tb_show("Choose a Shortcode", "#TB_inline?height=300&amp;width=400&amp;inlineId=" + optionValue + "");
}
</script>
```

And the HTML Content

```
<div id="shortcode_list" style="display:none">
    <label for="select"><span>Choose a shortcode</span></label>
    <select name="shortcodeOptions" onchange="showOptions();">
        <option>
            Select a shortcode
        </option>

        <option value="alert_div">
            Alert
        </option>

        <option value="button_div">
            Button
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```